# Is there a O(N) solution to getting top k most occurring string in List<String>?

Tags: java, string, performance, algorithm, word-frequency

The problem is: Given a list of strings and an integer k, return the top k most frequently occurring words in descending order based on frequency. This must be done O(N) where N is the length of the list of strings.

The popular solution is to store (word, frequency) in a hash table, sort the hash table by frequency, and output the top k words. This is not O(N) however because sorting by frequency takes O(NlgN).

I'm wondering if a O(N) solution actually exists. I've thought about quick-select where you get the kth top most occurring word and sort the remaining frequencies but that would be O(N + klgk) which is still O(NlgN) when k is say N.

Comment: Linear time suffix trees do exist, so I think you might be able to use them. But they're hard to implement. Suffix arrays might work too.

Comment: No need to sort all the n words; you can use a heap to store only the top k words; this should then be O(n logk) (n for all the words and logk for inserting them into a size-k heap.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does exist. There is no need to actually sort the pairs. One can find k-th element in O(n)(it's a well known algorithm). Then all elements that are greater than or equal to the k-th element are the top elements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a O(n) solution.

You can change the famous SELECT algorithm which running in complexity of O(n) to your needs 
(the algorithm purpose is to find the K'th smallest elements out of N elements).

and later you just pick the the elements which are "greater or equal" to the element the algorithm returns.

more details you can find at : [SELECT algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm)